# Using nw extensions in Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: netlogo, dijkstra

I'm now working on my undergraduate thesis about shortest path in Netlogo using Dijkstra algorithm

How nw extensions can be implemented in Dijkstra Algorithm coding?

Thank you. .

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question, but the NW extension uses Dijsktra's algorithm to do its shortest path calculations. The algorithm has been modified so as to save as much information as possible while running. You can read more about that here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#performance

If you're asking about using NW in order to write your own implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, NW doesn't really help you. It already has Dijkstra's built-in! You can implement Dijkstra's in NetLogo since all you really need is a way to get the links connected to a node and a data structure to store them in that makes it easy to grab the shortest one, called a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). The connected link calculation is easy (just `my-links` or `link-neighbors`; `other-end` is useful too). The heap is harder. NetLogo doesn't have a built-in heap, nor a good way of creating your own data structures, but you can build heaps just out of lists. You can also just use a list that remains sorted the whole time, but that will hurt the computational complexity.

Comment: Oh ok i understand now, can i use the weight [set weight ] to weight links when i'm using dijkstra algorithm coding, not the extensions? Or must I use other methods to weight the links? Thank you so much

Comment: If your weights are just in a `links-own` variable (let's call it `weight`), you can use that either from the extension or from your own implementation. For the extension, you'd do something like `nw:weighted-path-to target-node "weight"`.